# How to write a function to approximate the first partial derivatives

Tags: matlab, derivative

As stated in the title, I am trying to write a function which evaluates the partial derivative of f at a point (a,b).

However, the output of the partial derivative evaluated at (0,0) is way too large.

My supposition is that my algorithm for calculating the partial derivative is wrong. But I don't see how.

It has been a long time since I've last used MATLAB, so I do apologise if I've made some errors or used a inefficent way of writing my code.

My code is below:

```
function derivative = PartialDeriv(f, a, b, i)

    h = 0.0001;
    fn = zeros(1,2);

    if i == 1
        fn(i) = (f(a+h,b)-f(a,b)/h);
    elseif i==2
        fn(i) = (f(a,b+h)-f(a,b)/h);
    end

    derivative = fn(i);
end
```

Calling my function I get:

PartialDeriv(f, a, b, i)

where f is

```
f = @(x,y)(x-1).^2+(y-1).^2
```

I get:

```
f = -1.9998e+04
```

Doing it by hand I should get -2.

The **i** which is seen among the parameters for:

```
 PartialDeriv(f,a,b,i)
```

denotes my index, inorder to distinguish the partial derivative with respect to x and y.

Meaning that fn(1) is the partial derivative with respect to x and 
fn(2) is the partial derivative with respect to y.

Comment: Sorry for the title. I've now realized that it might be misleading

Comment: Please consider editing your title to something like "approximate calculation of partial derivatives" or something like that. As it is now, the first thought is that it has to do with solving a system of PDEs numerically with a finite difference/element scheme

Comment: @tryman good point. I was tasked however to solve it numerically for two variables. They have not mentioned finite difference/element scheme for my calc 3 course. Out of curiosity is there an advantage of using that method when solving for two varaibles?

Comment: " I am trying to write a function which evaluates the partial derivative at two points (a,b) for f." You are trying to evaluate the partial derivatives. In most cases, when saying you are trying to solve partial derivatives, you refer to the inverse process: Having the derivatives and trying to approximate the original function (look up PDEs: partial differential equations). Some of the possible methods for solving PDEs are finite elements and finite difference. That's why I suggested to edit out "solve numerically" from the title. Not applicable in this situation.

Comment: (Well... almost not applicable. What you already do by approximating the first partial derivative as `fn(i) = (f(a+h,b)-f(a,b))/h` is a finite difference scheme anyway, just not used to "solve" PDEs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've missed the parentheses in both cases.
It should be `fn(i) = (f(a+h,b)-f(a,b))/h;` instead of `fn(i) = (f(a+h,b)-f(a,b)/h);`.

Modifying your code a little, I believe this structure better suits your intent:

```
function derivative = PartialDeriv(f, a, b)
    h = 0.0001;
    derivative = zeros(1,2);
    derivative(1) = (f(a+h,b)-f(a,b))/h;
    derivative(2) = (f(a,b+h)-f(a,b))/h;
end
```